# list inside pandas dataframe cells

Tags: python, list, pandas

I have a data-frame like this:

[image]

and I want a new data-frame  with a new column which contains a list like this: 
[image]

How do I create a list inside a data-frame cell which contains the elements based on similar month?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let try, `set_index`, `groupby`, and `apply(list)`:

```
df.set_index('month', append=True).groupby(level=[0,1,2], sort=False)['from']\
  .apply(list).reset_index('month')
```

Output:

```
              month    from
google 2016      2     [e]
apple  2016      1  [b, c]
       2016      3     [l]
google 2016      3     [g]
```

Comment: Nice `set_index` :)

Answer (score 2):

Simpliest is use new functionality in pandas [`0.20.0+`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#groupby-enhancements) for groupby by levels and columns together:

```
df=df.groupby(['client','year','month'], sort=False)['from'].apply(list).reset_index('month')
print (df)
             month    from
client year               
google 2016      2     [e]
apple  2016      1  [b, c]
       2016      3     [l]
google 2016      3     [g]
```

For scalars with one element list solution is similar [`Wen`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45715716/2901002) - custom function with `if else`:

```
df=df.groupby(['client','year','month'], sort=False)['from'] \
     .apply(lambda x: list(x) if len(x)>1 else x.iat[0]).reset_index('month')
print (df)
             month    from
client year               
google 2016      2       e
apple  2016      1  [b, c]
       2016      3       l
google 2016      3       g
```

And for strings joined by `,` use `join` instead `list`:

```
df=df.groupby(['client','year','month'], sort=False)['from']
     .apply(', '.join).reset_index('month')
print (df)
             month  from
client year             
google 2016      2     e
apple  2016      1  b, c
       2016      3     l
google 2016      3     g
```

Answer (score 1):

My method almost the same with @Scott's answer, the only different is not convert single value to list.

```
    df.set_index('month', append=True).groupby(level=[0,1,2], sort=False)['from']\
      .apply(lambda x : x.tolist() if len(x)>1 else x.values[0]).reset_index('month')

              month    from
google 2016      2      e
apple  2016      1  [b, c]
       2016      3      l
google 2016      3      g
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you provided no code only excel like screenshots, know that it is possible to add a list as a value to the cell, for example by index:

```
df.loc[index, column_name] = list[b, c]
```

the datatype of the value will be object